# Flutter application Navigation Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app, sqflite

There are 2 screens in my application. In first screen I am listing all data from my sqflite database. In second screen I am giving functionality to delete that record. But when I pop that screen from the stack. It should be refreshed. How can I achieve that.

This is my first screen return code.

```
return FutureBuilder<List>(
      future: DatabaseHelper.instance.queryAll(),
      initialData: List(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? new ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                 
                  print("value : " + snapshot.data.toString());

                  return new Card(
                      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <
                          Widget>[
                  
                    ListTile(
                      leading:
                          Image.file(File(snapshot.data[i]["thumbnail_url"])),

                      title: Text(
                        snapshot.data[i]["title"],
                        style: _biggerFont,
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[i]["month"] +
                          ", " +
                          snapshot.data[i]["year"]),
                      
                      onTap: () {
                       
                      },
                    ),

                    ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Visibility(
                          visible: _isUrduAvail,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: const Text('اردو'),
                            onPressed: () {
                            
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => OfflinePdfViewer(
                                        snapshot.data[i]["id"].toString(),
                                        snapshot.data[i]["title"],
                                        snapshot.data[i]["urdu_url"],
                                        "Urdu")));
                           
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: _isEnglishAvail,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: const Text('English'),
                            onPressed: () {
                             
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => OfflinePdfViewer(
                                        snapshot.data[i]["id"].toString(),
                                        snapshot.data[i]["title"],
                                        snapshot.data[i]["english_url"],
                                        "English")));
                              
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Visibility(
                          visible: _isHindiAvail,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: const Text('हिन्दी'),
                            onPressed: () {
                             
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => OfflinePdfViewer(
                                        snapshot.data[i]["id"].toString(),
                                        snapshot.data[i]["title"],
                                        snapshot.data[i]["hindi_url"],
                                        "Hindi")));
                            
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ]));
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
      },
    );
```

In this screen i am building the list and populate the FutureBuilder.

and in second screen I have button on that button click the record will be deleted but what will be the route to call that it can be refreshed?

```
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => LibraryScreen(),
      ),
      (route) => false,
    );
```

I have tried this code but it clear all my activity stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call second screen try to use 'pushReplacement' instead of 'push'

Comment: will it refresh the list?

Comment: It should rebuild the whole screen.
But you will not be able to go back with 'pop' To go back you should use 'push' with route directed to your first/previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 'Pushreplacement' because it will dispose the previous route.

Comment: Okay, let me try this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you pushAndRemoveUntil you cannot go back to the same page. You need to push it again in which case the FutureBuilder will rebuild and you will see the correct data.

Or a better solution would be to get your data as a Stream instead of a Future and use StreamBuilder instead of FutureBuilder.